# Div containing checkbox falling down the containing div in firefox and chrome

Tags: html, asp.net, dhtml

I have a structure like

```
<div>
    <label>
        Name</label>
        <div style="text-align: right;">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chbName" class="checkbox" id="chbName"
        runat="server" checked="checked" /></div>
</div>
```

and smilar elements like these are in asp TableCell, for some reason the name and checkbox are not lined up horizontally.
Its like the div containing the checkbox is one step down in UI.
And this is happening in chrome and mozilla only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` is a block level element - it will appear below the label unless you give it one of the following styles:

```
display:inline;
display:inline-block;
float:left; (or right)
```

eg

```
<div style="text-align: right; display:inline-block;">
```

Comment: Thanks Pete, display:inline-blockn worked like a charm in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
```

by

```
<div style="float: right;">
```

Your complete HTML code like below...

```
     <div>
        <label>
            Name</label>
        <div style="float: right;">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chbName" class="checkbox" id="chbName" runat="server"
                checked="checked" /></div>
    </div>
```